# how to re-use single array of images to different activities?

Tags: arrays, image, android-activity, reference, share

I am Making an android application in that,
I have bunch of images, around 28 images actually, and I want to use those same images in different form in 3 different activities.
How am I suppose to do it?  so that I do not have to load same images from drawables to those 3 different activities.
Should I make an array.xml file ? and reference it.  or
Should I make an array class and then reference it ?
Thank You.

Comment: Please provide more context. Are you using javascript? Is it a web application? Are you using node? A lot more specifics would be helpful in answering your questions.

Comment: If you are just looking for design advice, then try this. Put the images into an array that all 3 methods/functions/"activities" have access to.

Comment: I am making an android application.

Comment: There are 3 different activities with image view in each activity, and same images are being loaded in those image views.

Comment: I feel loading the same images from drawables folder 3 times, I rather load it once and reference it to those image views.

Comment: I would add some tags to your question, and maybe update title so that it receives more views from people with knowledge in the stack your asking questions about.